# Unexpected array behavior in basic averaging program

Tags: c++, arrays, codeblocks, average

It seems like I always come here to ask silly questions, but here it goes. As of right now I am in my first compsci course and we are learning c++. I've had an extremely basic introduction to c before, so I had thought I'd go above and beyond my current assignment. Now I was doing this just to showboat, I felt like if I didn't practice my previous concepts they would eventually fade. Anyways, on to the problem! I was supposed to write some code that allowed the user to input their initials, and a series of exams. Now this was supposed to accomplish three things: average the exams, print out the entered exams, and print out their initials. Well, what was a simple assignment, got turned into a huge mess by yours truly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string uInitials;
  float avgExam = 0, tExam = 0;
  int aExams[10] = {'0'};
  int i, nExam = 0, cExam;


  cout << "Enter your three initials!";
  cin >> uInitials;


  do
      {

        cout << "Enter your exam(s) to be averaged. Enter 0 when          complete!\n";
        cin >> cExam;
        aExams[nExam] = cExam;  //I used this before nExam was incremented, in order to get nExam while it was '0' That way the first exam score would be properly saved in the first space
        nExam++;
        tExam += cExam;     //This is just to add all the exams up to later calculate the average
    }
  while(cExam != 0);

avgExam = tExam/(nExam - 1); //subtracted '1' from nExams to remove the  sentinel value from calculations.

cout << "The average for initials: " << uInitials << " is: " << avgExam <<   endl;
cout << "This average was obtained using the following scores that were entered: \n";

for(i = 0; i < (nExam+1); i++)
{
    cout << aExams[i] << endl; //Used a for loop to prevent redundancy
}

return 0;
}
```

The previous is my code, and the problem is that I'm getting output errors where it adds two '0's when I print out the list of entered exams. Also I feel like I made the whole do{}while() loop one huge clunky mess, so I'd like to refine that as well. If anyone could assist this poor, ignorant, beginner I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you for your time!

Comment: No guard to prevent overrunning the end of the buffer on the input

Comment: Are you using an IDE? If so which one?

Comment: I'm using code::blocks! It's the one I'm the most comfortable with.

Comment: Code::blocks front ends the GDB debugger. You'll have a bit of a learning curve, but there is nothing more useful in the long term than figuring out how to debug your own code. Your current problem is trivial to spot if you step through the code.

Comment: Do not use C-style arrays. Use `std::array` or `std::vector` which are bounds checked by good debuggers and will detect many errors. Vector also allows you to resize as needed and not pick an arbitrary number such as 10 which will break if more than 10 elements are needed. `= {'0'};` does not set an array of `int` to all 0s (check your debugger). Use `= {};` instead. (Unnecessary for vectors which 0 out automatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some advice that i can give is for example in the 5th line there is no need
to put the 0 between ' ' and not even need to use the assign = operator.
You can initialize the array like this:
int aExams[10]{0};
Which will initialize all elements to 0,but can't be used for other value.
For example you won't have all the elements with value 1 if you write
int aExams[10]{1};
If your intention to initialize all elements in an array is with value other than 0 you can use fill_n(); function.

fill_n(aExams, 10, 1);
The first argument is the name of the array, the second is up-to which element you want to be initialized with the third argument, and the third is the value you want all elements to have.

Do not leave uninitialized variables like in line 6 with cExam and i variables. Initialize it like cExam=0; (copy-assign initialization) or cExam(0); (direct initialization). The latter calls the constructor for int built-in type.

A negative i see in your do-while loop is that you do not make sure that the user will enter under 10 exams,bad things will happen if the user tries to input 15 exams in an array that can hold only 10.

Just change the while to something more like this:
  while( cExam != 0 && (nExam<10) );

You can also write the first two lines of the do-while loop outside the loop.
It is needed only once to tell the user that to stop the loop he/she needs to enter 0. There is no need to tell them this on every iteration plus that you will have a good performance benefit if you put those two lines outside the loop.

Look here how i would write the code and ask if you have any questions.

http://pastebin.com/3BFzrk5C

Comment: I actually did have a few questions if you didn't mind instructing me! Note that I'm not attempting to insinuate that I know more than you, but these were just some thoughts that occurred to me while looking through your improved code.


1.) I noticed that you changed to a while loop and instead ran a 'cin >> cExam;' call outside of the while loop, and again inside of the while loop. Wouldn't it technically be more efficient to just call it once during the do{}while()? Is there an issue with using a do()while{}?

P.S. I'm running out of characters, I'll ask my other questions in other comments

Comment: 2.) I suspect there is an error, but I wanted to ask just in case I was just ignorant. In line 21 of your code you removed the (nExam - 1) that I put there to remove the sentinel value from being include in the average calculation. Was there a particular reason?

3.)My last question, I noticed that you replaced a lot of my 'endl' usages with '\n' and even did a cout<<endl after the for loop. What was  the purpose? Is it appropriate to use one over the other in some contexts?
(Some examples of this was in line 24, and again in line 28)

Comment: 1) In my code-i switched to a while loop and did one cin>>cExam; before even trying to enter the loop, that way before going to the while i already have some value in cExam that can be evaluated and the compiler will decide will it execute the while or not. Look at your do-while loop,what will happen if your first value is 0? Since it is a do loop,the code in the body will be executed,and you do not want this,you want 0 as a control number to exit the loop.

Comment: 1) at any point if you enter 0 it will be first added into the array and then it will exit the loop.

Comment: You do not want a 0 in your array. 2) I do not need to decrement nExam because i have the exact number of elements.Look at this example: I enter for cExam 10,then nExam becomes 1,i enter for cExam 5, then nExam becomes 2 i enter for cExam 0 and get out of the loop but nExam does not increment so it is not 3 but 2,just as much elements as i have entered. As for the \n and endl. \n means newline while endl is newline and buffer flush,you do not need to flush the buffer on every iteration in the for loop,only after the loop,to make sure that everything in memory is printed out.

Comment: I see, now that you've explained it to me I understand now. Thank you for being patient and taking the time to answer my question!

Answer (score 1):

The problem where it prints out two 0's at the end of your code is a result of the way you wrote your for loop.

Instead of:

```
for(i = 0; i < (nExam+1); i++)
{
    cout << aExams[i] << endl; //Used a for loop to prevent redundancy
}
```

Use:

```
for (i = 1; i < (nExam); i++)
{
    cout << aExams[i - 1] << endl; //Used a for loop to prevent redundancy
}
```

Comment: A fatal problem, but it's likely the OP has already crashed by this point. Recommend adding an explanation of why the do/while loop is wrong.

Comment: So I think I recognize why you suggested to do this method. Basically by allowing the for loop to stop while it is less than the value of nExams it will drop the sentinel value of '0' from the output. The problem is, when I made this change, it instead game me a trash number first output. To show this, my output after the change (while inputting three 100 "scores" for testing) is:

268716
100
100
100